# Where to get all the C header files located in /usr/include?

Tags: c, header-files, gtk3, clion

There are two things you should know

1. Using Kali Linux
2. I am  a noob

Okay getting to the problem. I was using Clion for coding my C projects and everything was fair and well but suddenly I wanted to make GUI apps with C so I google and found GTK to be the best choice. Went to their websites downloaded all the required files installed them also installed the dependencies files everything went well. The strange thing was that the gtk header files were not directly included in the /usr/include instead there was a file "gtk-3.o" which contained the gtk and gdk header files. So curse my noobness i always tried to include the 'gtk-3.o' instead of doing it like this `#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>` and whenever i did this i got error. Then I did the stupidest thing one could ever think of, I copied ALL the files in the gtk-3.0 folder and pasted them directly into the /usr/include. Now when i include the required files like including gtk.h and after that including gdk.h and after that one other file (forgot the name) i get an error saying only gtk.h can be included directly. I googled this error and found a guy saying that The GTK guys did not want the gtk files to be directly included in /usr/include due to unmet dependencies of some of their header files. A guy commented below that he included the gtk files like through subdirectory and worked fine but now i cannot do this because I have copied the contents of gtk-3.0 in /usr/include. I have completely removed Clion and am thinking of deleting the contents of /usr/include and maybe reinstalling Clion will get the header files back. If this is not going to happen please direct me how to get the header files or a better alternative to this solution if there is. Help would be highly appreciated because i have spent my entire day trying to solve this problem, I am exhausted and want some expert help. Thanks

Note: I have not yet deleted the /usr/include/

Comment: You install *development packages*. They should contain the header files (among other things). For example say you want to make a program that uses library X, then you need to install the packages containing the actual library (usually named something like `libX` or similar). That will give you the library only. To get the header files needed to build a program using the library you install the development packages (usually names something like `X-dev` or `libX-dev`). Exact names depend on your Linux distribution.

Comment: `/usr/include` is part of your operating system. You should not have touched it (I'm not the downvoter though).

Comment: @RustyX i know i should not have but now what do i do i am so tensed :(

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling GCC and related packages.

Comment: @RustyX you sure that would solve my problem, i was thinking of re-installing the OS. That would for sure solve my problem.

Comment: @SawairaKhan that would be like killing mosquitos with a bazooka. Reinstalling gcc and related packages may not solve the problem. But reinstalling the OS (instead of, e.g., trying to delete the files you copied) is quite an overreaction.

Comment: @FedericoklezCUlloca i too was think of deleting the files individually but i am way too tired to do all that i want a quick and easy solution

Comment: I have removed gcc from my pc but the header files are still there. How do i remove them also? Is it because of gcc related packages?

Comment: @RustyX How would reinstalling gcc help? It's just a C compiler; it doesn't own `/usr/include`.

Comment: Reinstall the OS. It is painful but hopefully you won't repeat the same mistake again. Only install software from your OS package repository.

Comment: @n.m I have deleted all the files in /usr/include now i am upgrading using sudo apt-get upgrade and after that i'll dist-upgrade. May be it'll help. Let's see

Comment: Try to break your question into paragraphs, It's very hard to read.

Comment: What is the actual question? "How do I re-install Clion" or "How do I install gtk3?" It would seem that either question could be summarized with just a few sentences and some brief description of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** manually mess with files in `/usr` unless you are **absolutely** sure what you are doing.

Once you messed up your `/usr`, depending on how bad it is, you might be able to fix it by re-installing the packages affected, but you might also end up reinstalling the operating system entirely.

Once you have a working OS, here is how you should get started.
Unfortunately, I've never used Kali Linux, but I'll try to word the answer in a way that is applicable to most distributions.

## The general solution

### Install a compiler

You are going to need a compiler. If you want to use C, I suggest **gcc** or **clang**. You also need **make** and maybe other build tools like cmake, qmake, meson, etc.

Most distributions have a *build-essential* metapackage that you can install.

I also strongly suggest to install `pkg-config`.

### Install a library for development

Install the library that you want to use and its **development package** from your distribution's package manager. On Debian-based systems, the development packages are postfixed with `-dev`, on Fedora-based systems they are postfixed with `-devel`.So if you want to use `mylibrary`, you need to:

```
# On Debian-based systems
apt-get install mylibrary mylibrary-dev
# On Fedora-based systems
dnf install mylibrary mylibrary-devel
```

Notes:

- Unless you are **absolutely** sure what you are doing, **always** install software through your distribution's package manager, and **never** from 3rd parties, and **especially never** from random places on the internet.
- Some distributions use other package managers, eg. `pacman`, `zypper`, `pkcon`, etc. [You can check this wikipage to see how they correlate.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta)
- If you are not sure what is the name of the package, you can use the search functionality of your package manager, or you can search on your distribution's package database website.

### Use the library

You write some code, include the library's headers and call some functions. Then when you try to compile your code, the compiler will tell you that it can't find those includes and it can't find the definitions of the functions you want to use.

Tell the compiler that you want to use the library.

You can do this by setting the include paths with `-I` and add the library to the linker with `-l`. If you are unsure about exactly what you should pass to the compiler, `pkg-config` comes to your rescue:

The following commands will tell you what you need to tell the compiler:

```
pkg-config --cflags mylibrary
pkg-config --libs mylibrary
```

So the compilation command looks like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mylibrary -lmylibrary yourcode.c
```

Notes:

- As far as `pkg-config` is concerned, the name of the library doesn't always match the name of the package you install with `apt-get` or `dnf`. You can find out the name by looking at `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` or a similar location. (On Fedora-based 64-bit systems its `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig`, on other distributions it might be somewhere else.)

### Use a build tool

While it is very much worth to understand the above process, it quickly becomes very tedious to write all those commands by hand all the time (especially for larger projects), so you could use a build tool like cmake, qmake, meson, etc. which will generate those commands for you.

These tools are out of scope for this already long answer, but feel free to search the web for them, you will surely find a tutorial.

## Creating a GTK app

After the above explanation, let's see how all of that works in practice. I'll show you how to compile a very simple GTK app.

I use Fedora, but the steps are similar on any other GNU/Linux distribution.

First, install GTK and its development package

```
# Fedora
dnf install gtk3-devel
# Debian
apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

I used Google to search for some GTK example code and found [their getting started page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). So take the following example code and save it in `example.c`:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Then figure out the pkgconfig name:

```
# Note: the location might be different on your system, see above
ls /usr/lib64/pkgconfig | grep gtk
```

So the pkgconfig name is `gtk+-3.0`.
Now to figure out the correct compiler flags:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

Which outputs the following:

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

**The result will be different on your machine. Use the result from this command that you get on your machine!** So don't copy-paste this command because it will not work for you. Compile the example code using your result of the pkgconfig command:

```
gcc example.c -o example -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Or simply:

```
gcc example.c -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Which correctly compiles the program.

Let's run it:

```
./example
```

Aaaand hooray! It displays an empty GTK window, just as we expect.
If you want to know more, see [Getting Started with GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) and [Compiling GTK+ Applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-compiling.html).

Comment: I deleted the files present in include and then upgraded my distro. Fortunately i got the header files back. But still i am getting the error. Like if i  include #include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h> and compile i get the error and if i include #include <gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h> to resolve this error i get another error saying gdk/gdkconfig.h: No such file or directory and to resolve this if i include #include <gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h> i get the error #error "Only <gdk/gdk.h> can be included directly." What do i need to do to successfully use GTK in my c program. using clion by the way

Comment: @SawairaKhan I edited my answer to show how to compile a simple GTK program too.